# How to change the color of lines in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

Image showing what I want to change

[image]

What property in layout is responsible for those lines? I want them to be the same color as the font.

Answer (score 2):

That would be `figure.layout.yaxis.gridcolor`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23325832)

Comment: The question is literally what is the property in layout to change the color of the lines, this is exactly the property that allows you to change the color of the lines, I do not see how that is not the right answer to the question.